# Transfering specific rows from one cvs file to another cvs file

Tags: python, csv

So, I'm trying to transfer rows[0,1,2,9,10] from what I've designated as "e_file" to "no_file"

When I print "data" I am given the exact information I want, I was just wondering how I should proceed with transferring this data to a corresponding CSV file?

Thank you.

```
e_file = '/Users/massive/Desktop//NO/hour.csv'
no_file = '/Users/massive/Desktop/NO/combined.csv'

with open(e_file,'r') as e_r:

    state_code = input("Enter state code: ")
    county_code = input("Enter county code: ")
    station_number = input("Enter station number: ")

    csv_reader_2 = csv.reader(e_r)

    for row in csv_reader_2:

       if row[0] == str(state_code).zfill(2) and row[1] ==str(county_code).zfill(3) and row[2] == str(station_number).zfill(4):
           data = [row[0],row[1],row[2],row[9],row[10]]
           print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like (I cannot test it unless you provide a working example):

```
with open(newFile, 'wb') as csvfile:
    fwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for line in data:
        fwriter.writerow(line)
```